# Rails 'includes' and 'where' with belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**I have 2 models: PassportVisa and Country.**

**Country Model**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iso, :name
  has_many :passport_visa, foreign_key: :country_id
end
```

**PassportVisa Model**

```
class PassportVisa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country, foreign_key: :country_id
end
```

And I'm trying to query the passportvisa model like that:

```
@passport_visa_supplement_o   = PassportVisa.includes(:assets).where(:visa_type => 'Official' ,:assets => {:pdf_type => 'supplement'}).order("country ASC")
```

But it says that:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  column "country" does not exist

It's because on my PassportVisa table I only have access to the country_id. Using that same query (with a few adjustments) How can I automatically get the country name?

> The :assets is from another model that I'm using for upload, it should stay there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not including the country table in your joins.

if you want to order for country name you can just do

```
@passport_visa_supplement_o = PassportVisa.includes([:assets, :country]).uniq.where(:visa_type => 'Official' ,:assets => {:pdf_type => 'supplement'}).order("countries.name ASC")
```

I added the `.uniq` because with the outer join you could have duplicates